# Prove that $\Bbb{E}(|X-Y|) \le \Bbb{E}(|X+Y|)$ for i.i.d $X$ and $Y$

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, expectation

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent identically distributed random
>   variables with finite expectation $\Bbb{E}(X) = \Bbb{E}(Y) < \infty$. Prove that
>
> $$\Bbb{E}(|X-Y|) \le \Bbb{E}(|X+Y|)$$

I think that this inequality may follow somehow from [Jensen's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality#General_inequality_in_a_probabilistic_setting), but I failed to use it here. Or maybe it is worth considering an expression $|x+y|-|x-y|$ and making use of some of its properties?

I am interested to see a proof of this fact or some favorable ideas that may help here. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note. For $X$ and $Y$ with symmetric distributions, it results in equality.

Comment: Maybe the fact that the expected of $X-Y $ is zerocould be useful.

Comment: @Boby Yes, it does. Does this fact help to solve the problem somehow?

Comment: @Ramil It only points to a fact that if you want to find meaningful examples, you have to look at asymmetric distributions.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/399368/321264

Answer (score 36, accepted):

By a simple $u$-substitution, we find that

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos(at)}{t^2} \, \mathrm{d}t = C|a|, \tag{1}$$

where $C = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos t}{t^2} \, \mathrm{d}t$ is a positive, finite constant. (It can be shown that $C = \pi$, although the exact value of $C$ plays no role in this solution.)

Note that the integrand of $\text{(1)}$ is non-negative. Taking advantage of this fact, we can apply [*Tonelli's theorem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli.27s_theorem_for_non-negative_functions) to find that, for *any* real-valued random variable $Z$, the following identity holds:

$$ \Bbb{E}[|Z|]
= \frac{1}{C} \Bbb{E}\left[ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos(Zt)}{t^2} \, \mathrm{d}t \right]
= \frac{1}{C} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1-\Bbb{E}[\cos(Zt)]}{t^2} \, \mathrm{d}t $$

Therefore

\begin{align*}
\Bbb{E}[|X+Y| - |X-Y|]
&= \frac{1}{C} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\Bbb{E}[\cos((X-Y)t)-\cos((X+Y)t)]}{t^2} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \frac{1}{C} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\Bbb{E}[2\sin(Xt)\sin(Yt)]}{t^2} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&= \frac{1}{C} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{2\Bbb{E}[\sin(Xt)]^2}{t^2} \, \mathrm{d}t \\
&\geq 0. \tag{2}
\end{align*}

Moreover, the equality holds for $\text{(2)}$ if and only if $\Bbb{E}[\sin(Xt)] = 0$ for all $t$. This implies  that the characteristic function $\varphi_X(t) = \Bbb{E}[e^{itX}]$ is real-valued, which in turn is equivalent to the symmetry condition: $X \stackrel{d}{=} -X$.

---

*Remark.* Using a similar argument, we can show that:

> **Theorem.** Let $p \in (0, 2]$, and let $X$ and $Y$ be i.i.d. $L^p$-random variables. Then
>
> $$\mathbb{E}[|X+Y|^p] \geq \mathbb{E}[|X-Y|^p]. $$
>
> Moreover, the equality holds if and only if $X \stackrel{d}{=} -X$.

Comment: Wow! You did it again! Could you please reveal how on earth did you come up with such a solution? It doesn't seem to be quite natural. What is the intuition behind such solutions?

Comment: Can this argument be extended to $E[|X+Y|^p] -E[|X-Y|^p] $ ?

Comment: @Ramil, As in the previous problem, I thought that it would be nice to have a representation that allows to split $|X-Y|$. Among integrals that I know, $\text{(1)}$ seemed useful for my purpose, so I tried it and luckily it worked :)

Comment: @Boby, The argument readily extends to $p \in (0, 2)$ from the identity $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos(at)}{t^{1+p}} \, dt = \frac{\pi}{2 \Gamma(1+p)\sin(\pi p/2)} |a|^p. $$ The case $p = 0, 2$ are just algebra. For $p > 2$, I am not sure even the inequality remains true.

Comment: Great. Thank you. It is interesting that it holds for $p<1$. Since, $|a|^p$ for $p<1$ no longer induces a norm.

Comment: @Boby It is not true in some cases. Say, for $p=4$ we have $(X+Y)^4 - (X-Y)^4 = 12X^3Y + 12Y^3X$, so $\Bbb{E}((X+Y)^4 - (X-Y)^4) = 24\Bbb{E}(X^3)\Bbb{E}(Y)$ and, for example, for $X, Y$ that are always negative the expectation will be negative.

Comment: @Boby, You're right. Even it is not entirely clear to me what kind of 'balancing' in joint distribution of $X-Y$ and $X+Y$ makes this happen.

Comment: I suggest we put this as a question. What do you think?

Comment: @Boby, Sure, it is always nice to see different perspectives.

Comment: @Ramil If $P(X\leqslant0)=1$ then $E(X^3)E(X)\geqslant0$ hence this is is not a counterexample. But it suffices that $E(X)$ and $E(X^3)$ have opposite signs, for example if $P(X=-1)=\frac34$, $P(X=2)=\frac14$,

Comment: @Did Yes, you are right, thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Here's another argument. It doesn't seem to generalize to $p$ norms, but perhaps it is instructive anyway.

For independent variables $X,Y$ with finite expectation we can write

\begin{align*}
\mathbb E|X-Y|
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathbb P[X\leq t< Y]+\mathbb P[Y\leq t<X] dt\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty F_X(t)(1-F_Y(t))+F_Y(t)(1-F_X(t)) dt\tag{1}
\end{align*}

where $F_Z$ denotes the cumulative distribution function $F_Z(t)=\mathbb P[Z\leq t]$ of a random variable $Z.$

In the case at hand, $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d., so $F_{-Y}(t)=1-F_X(-t).$ Using $-Y$ instead of $Y$ in (1) gives

$$\mathbb E|X+Y|=\int_{-\infty}^\infty F_X(t)F_X(-t)+(1-F_X(-t))(1-F_X(t)) dt\tag{2}$$

We can get a comparable integrand for $\mathbb E|X-Y|$ by substituting $t$ for $-t$ in the final term in (1), and using $F_Y=F_X$:
$$
\mathbb E|X-Y|=\int_{-\infty}^\infty F_X(t)(1-F_X(t))+F_X(-t)(1-F_X(-t)) dt\tag{3}
$$

Writing $a=F_X(t)$ and $b=F_X(-t),$ clearly $((1-a)-b)((1-b)-a)=(1-a-b)^2\geq 0,$
so $a(1-a)+b(1-b)\leq ab+(1-a)(1-b).$ Integrating over $t$ and applying (3) and (2) gives $\mathbb E|X-Y|\leq \mathbb E|X+Y|.$ The equality case is when $F_X(-t)+F_X(t)=1$ a.e., which is when $X$ is symmetric about zero.

Comment: Very instructive solution indeed. Can you show me how to derive this formula for the expected value $\mathbb{E}|X-Y|= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}[X\leq t < Y] + \mathbb{P}[Y\leq y < X] dt$ ?

Comment: Curtis74: You need to replace $y$ by $t$. The formula is clear when $X,Y$ are constant, so it holds if you condition on the values of $X,Y$ on both sides. Now take expectations using Tonnelli on the RHS.

Answer (score 2):

Way late to the party, but here's another approach. First verify the identity
$$
|x+y|-|x-y|=2[\min(x^+,y^+)+\min(x^-,y^-)-\min(x^+,y^-)-\min(x^-,y^+)].\tag1$$
Next, use [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/172841/215011) to argue that for nonnegative and independent $U$ and $V$:
$$E\min(U,V)=\int_0^\infty P(\min(U,V)>t)\,dt=\int_0^\infty P(U>t)P(V>t)\,dt.\tag2
$$
Apply (2) four times to find, when $X$ and $Y$ are iid,
$$
\begin{aligned}
E\min(X^+,Y^+)&=\int_0^\infty P(X^+>t)P(Y^+>t)\,dt=\int_0^\infty 
P(X>t)P(X>t)\,dt\\
E\min(X^-,Y^-)&=\int_0^\infty P(X^->t)P(Y^->t)\,dt=\int_0^\infty 
P(-X>t)P(-X>t)\,dt\\
E\min(X^+,Y^-)&=\int_0^\infty P(X^+>t)P(Y^->t)\,dt=\int_0^\infty 
P(X>t)P(-X>t)\,dt\\
E\min(X^-,Y^+)&=\int_0^\infty P(X^->t)P(Y^+>t)\,dt=\int_0^\infty 
P(-X>t)P(X>t)\,dt
\end{aligned}$$
Put everything together:
$$E|X+Y|-E|X-Y|=2\int_0^\infty[P(X>t)-P(-X>t)]^2\,dt.$$ This final quantity is nonnegative, and equals zero iff $X$ has symmetric distribution about $0$.