# Validity of integral formula for $E[|X + Y|] - E[|X - Y|]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expected-value

$\newcommand{\real}{\mathbb{R}}$
I read this identity from the monograph *Probability Inequalities* by Zhengyan Lin and Zhidong Bai.  The author proposed to use this identity to prove the inequality $E[|X - Y|] \leq E[|X + Y|]$ when $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d.  I quote:

> *An alternative proof is to use the formula
> \begin{align}
>  & E[|X + Y|] - E[|X - Y|] \\
> =& \int_{-\infty}^\infty(1 - F(u) - F(-u))(1 - G(u) - G(-u))du, \tag{1}
> \end{align}
> where $F$ and $G$ are the distribution functions of $X$ and $Y$ respectively.*

The author didn't give a proof to $(1)$ (assume $X$ and $Y$ are independent). In the original text, the lower limit of the integral is
"$0$", which has been corrected to "$-\infty$" in $(1)$.

My question:  does $(1)$ hold for any distribution functions $F$ and $G$ (such that $E[|X|] < \infty, E[|Y|] < \infty$)? The author seems to imply this is the case. As shown below, $(1)$ is indeed true if $F$ and $G$ are absolutely continuous with densities $f$ and $g$, but I have difficulty to generalize it to any distribution functions.  Interestingly, $E[|X - Y|] \leq 
E[|X + Y|]$ holds for general i.i.d. $X$ and $Y$, as proved elegantly in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2251389/192408).

---

My attempt:  When $F$ and $G$ have densities $f$ and $g$ respectively, direct simplification shows
\begin{align}
 & E[|X + Y|] - E[|X - Y|] \\
=& 2E[X(1 - G(X) - G(-X))] + 2E[Y(1 - F(Y) - F(-Y))] \\
=& 2\int_\real x(1 - G(x) - G(-x))f(x)dx + 2\int_\real x(1 - F(x) - F(-x))g(x)dx.
\end{align}
By the change of variable theorem:
\begin{align}
I = \int_\real x(1 - G(x) - G(-x))f(x)dx = \int_\real (-t)(1 - G(-t) - G(t))f(-t)dt.
\end{align}
Hence
\begin{align}
 & 2I = \int_\real x(1 - G(x) - G(-x))(f(x) - f(-x))dx \\
=& -\int_\real x(1 - G(x) - G(-x))d(1 - F(-x) - F(x)). \tag{2}
\end{align}
Similarly, if denote $E[Y(1 - F(Y) - F(-Y)]$ by $J$, then
\begin{align}
2J = -\int_\real x(1 - F(x) - G(-x))d(1 - G(-x) - G(x)). \tag{3}
\end{align}

Integrating by parts, $-2I$ becomes
\begin{align}
  & x(1 - G(x) - G(-x))(1 - F(x) - F(-x))|_{-\infty}^\infty \\
 -& \int_\real (1 - F(x) - F(-x))(1 - G(x) - G(-x))dx \\
 -& \int_\real x(1 - F(x) - F(-x))d(1 - G(x) - G(-x)) \\
 =& -\int_\real (1 - F(x) - F(-x))(1 - G(x) - G(-x))dx + 2J,
\end{align}
hence
\begin{align}
 & E[|X + Y|] - E[|X - Y|] \\
=& 2(I + J) = \int_\real (1 - F(x) - F(-x))(1 - G(x) - G(-x))dx. 
\end{align}
That $\lim_{x \to \pm\infty}x(1 - F(x) - F(-x))(1 - G(x) - G(-x)) = 0$ in the above derivation can be derived by integrability of $X$ or $Y$.  For example, for sufficiently positive large $x$:
\begin{align}
0 \leq x(1 - F(x) - F(-x))(1 - G(x) - G(-x)) \leq x(1 - F(x)) \to 0
\end{align}
as $x \to \infty$ ($x(1 - F(x)) \to 0$ as $x \to +\infty$ is well known if $E[|X|] < \infty$).

I think the difficulty of generalizing the above argument to general $F$ and $G$ lies in deriving $(2)$ and $(3)$, in particular when $F$ and $G$ have discontinuities.  Therefore, I doubt if $(1)$ can still hold for the general case (perhaps some extra discrete terms need to be appended).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\real}{\mathbb{R}}$
Without assuming the differentiability of $F$ and $G$, $(1)$ can be proved by using an integration representation of $|X - Y|$ and $|X + Y|$ as follows (inspired by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3125111/192408)).

Note that for real numbers $x$ and $y$, we have
\begin{align}
& |x - y| = \int_\real \left[I_{[x, \infty)}(u)I_{(-\infty, y)}(u) + I_{[y, \infty)}(u)I_{(-\infty, x)}(u)\right]du, \\
& |x + y| = \int_\real \left[I_{(-y, \infty)}(u)I_{(-\infty, x)}(u) + I_{[x, \infty)}(u)I_{(-\infty, -y]}(u)\right]du,
\end{align}
where $I_A(x)$ stands for the indicator function: $I_A(x) = 1$ if $x \in A$ and $0$ otherwise.  Therefore,
\begin{align}
& |X - Y| = \int_\real\left[I_{[X, \infty)}(u)I_{(-\infty, Y)}(u) + I_{[Y, \infty)}(u)I_{(-\infty, X)}(u)\right]du, \tag{1} \\
& |X + Y| = \int_\real\left[I_{(-Y, \infty)}(u)I_{(-\infty, X)}(u) + I_{[X, \infty)}(u)I_{(-\infty, -Y]}(u)\right]du. \tag{2}
\end{align}
It thus follows by the independence of $X$ and $Y$, the change of variable theorem, and the Tonelli's theorem that
\begin{align}
 & E[|X - Y|] \\
=& \int_\Omega\left\{\int_\real \left[I_{[X, \infty)}(u)I_{(-\infty, Y)}(u) + I_{[Y, \infty)}(u)I_{(-\infty, X)}(u)\right]du\right\} dP \\
=& \int_{\real^2}\left\{\int_\real \left[I_{[x, \infty)}(u)I_{(-\infty, y)}(u) + I_{[y, \infty)}(u)I_{(-\infty, x)}(u)\right]du\right\} dF(x)dG(y) \\
=& \int_{\real}\left\{\int_{\real^2} \left[I_{(-\infty, u]}(x)I_{(u, \infty)}(y) + I_{(-\infty, u]}(y)I_{(u, \infty)}(x)\right]dF(x)dG(y)\right\} du \\
=& \int_{\real}\left\{\int_\real I_{(-\infty, u]}(x)dF(x)\int_\real I_{(u, \infty)}(y)dG(y) + \int_\real I_{(-\infty, u]}(y)dG(y)\int_\real I_{(u, \infty)}(x)dF(x)\right\} du \\
=& \int_{\real}\left\{F(u)(1 - G(u)) + G(u)(1 - F(u)\right\} du. \tag{3}
\end{align}

By $(2)$, similar calculation yields
\begin{align}
 & E[|X + Y|] \\
=& \int_\Omega\left\{\int_\real\left[I_{(-Y, \infty)}(u)I_{(-\infty, X)}(u) + I_{[X, \infty)}(u)I_{(-\infty, -Y]}(u)\right]du\right\} dP \\
=& \int_{\real^2}\left\{\int_\real \left[I_{(-y, \infty)}(u)I_{(-\infty, x)}(u) + I_{[x, \infty)}(u)I_{(-\infty, -y]}(u)\right]du\right\} dF(x)dG(y) \\
=& \int_{\real}\left\{\int_{\real^2}\left[I_{(-u, \infty)}(y)I_{(u, \infty)}(x) + I_{(-\infty, u]}(x)I_{(-\infty, -u]}(y)\right]dF(x)dG(y)\right\} du \\
=& \int_{\real}\left\{\int_\real I_{(-u, \infty)}(y)dG(y)\int_\real I_{(u, \infty)}(x)dF(x) + \int_\real I_{(-\infty, u]}(x)dF(x)\int_\real I_{(-\infty, -u]}(y)dG(y)\right\} du \\
=& \int_{\real}\left\{(1 - F(u))(1 - G(-u)) + F(u)G(-u)\right\}du. \tag{4}
\end{align}

Subtracting $(3)$ from $(4)$ gives the desired formula:
\begin{align}
E[|X + Y|] - E[|X - Y|] 
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty(1 - F(u) - F(-u))(1 - G(u) - G(-u))du.  
\end{align}

Therefore, the referenced formula is indeed sufficiently general.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more concise derivation, a modification of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4851754/215011): First verify the identity
$$
|x+y|-|x-y|=2[\min(x^+,y^+)+\min(x^-,y^-)-\min(x^+,y^-)-\min(x^-,y^+)].$$
Next, use [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/172841/215011) to argue that for nonnegative and independent $U$ and $V$:
$$E\min(U,V)=\int_0^\infty P(\min(U,V)>t)\,dt=\int_0^\infty P(U>t)P(V>t)\,dt.
$$
Apply this last to find, when $X$ and $Y$ are independent,
$$
\begin{aligned}
E\min(X^+,Y^+)&=\int_0^\infty P(X^+>t)P(Y^+>t)\,dt=\int_0^\infty 
P(X>t)P(Y>t)\,dt\\
E\min(X^-,Y^-)&=\int_0^\infty P(X^->t)P(Y^->t)\,dt=\int_0^\infty 
P(-X>t)P(-Y>t)\,dt\\
E\min(X^+,Y^-)&=\int_0^\infty P(X^+>t)P(Y^->t)\,dt=\int_0^\infty 
P(X>t)P(-Y>t)\,dt\\
E\min(X^-,Y^+)&=\int_0^\infty P(X^->t)P(Y^+>t)\,dt=\int_0^\infty 
P(-X>t)P(Y>t)\,dt
\end{aligned}$$
Put everything together:
$$E|X+Y|-E|X-Y|=2\int_0^\infty[P(X>t)-P(-X>t)][P(Y>t)-P(-Y>t)]\,dt.$$
This is the same as the desired identity (1), since $P(X>t)=1-F(t)$ and $P(-X>t)=F(-t)$ for almost every $t$ (similarly for $Y$, $G$), and the integrand in (1) is an even function of $u$.